# POST request to create a resource with bulk data from a csv file

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have used *Python* for many of my projects but I am new to *django* and the *django rest framework*, which I am using to design and develop a set of Web APIs for my current project.

Weaving the backend, we are using *Postgres* for user information and *DynamoDb* for other set of resources users have to work upon.

In the basic implementation, I tried to write the viewset as below:

```
class WorkViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.WorkSerializer
    permission_map = {
        'create'             : [IsAuthenticated, IsUser, ],  # post
        'list'               : [IsAuthenticated, ],          # get
        'retrieve'           : [IsAuthenticated, ],          # get
        'work_approval'      : [IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin, ], # post
        'work_disapproval'   : [IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin, ], # post
    }

    def list(self, request):
        ...

    def create(self, request):
        ...

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        ...

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True, url_path='approve', url_name='work_approval')
    def work_approval(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True, url_path='disapprove', url_name='work_disapproval')
    def work_disapproval(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def get_permissions(self):
        try:
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_map[self.action]]
        except KeyError:
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

and the serializer as below:

```
class WorkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    STATUSES = (
        '0',
        '1',
        '2',
    )
    work_id     = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    work_name   = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    work_type   = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    work_status = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STATUSES, default='0')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```

This set of code is working absolutely fine for me, but with latest requirement changes, I need to configure the POST request to additionally accept a csv file and parse this file to extract the contents which must be pushed to database in additional fields (not as file field). I tried to look for the solutions to this problem and found this [link](https://imju.me/bulk-update-on-rest-framework-b4403f8b6f9b) but this solution mainly targets bulk submission of single type of resource which differs from my need.

I am using *Python 3.6.5*, *Django 2.0.6* and *Django Rest Framework 3.8.2*

Please help me how should I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your serializer to include a CSV file:

```
class WorkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    csv_file = serializers.FileField()
```

in serializer's create function:

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
     csv_input = validated_data.pop("csv_file", None)
     instance = super().create(validated_data)

     if csv_input: 
          ** Process your csv file **

     return instance
```

Personally, i would suggest you to create a background to process csv files and update DB. Because thsi could be long running task.
So instead of processing the csv file directly during the POST request, you would schedule a task.

**Updated to answer the comment**

Background processing - it requires little bit of configuration and you have multiple ways you can choose from. Perhaps, the easiest is to use [django background tasks](http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
And this would serve your purpose well. You simple create a function, add background decorator and when it is called, a task is scheduled.

> Do you think if this approach of using a csv file to post bulk data is a good one or we should use a huge json instead ?

Well that depends.

If you upload a file, you will need to configure a storage for it where your scheduled task has access to ( local or remote one , again depends on your use case ).
One huge json - hm, that depends how huge is huge. You would need to run some test to determine where are your limits.

Maybe a possible solution would be to upload your csv file directly to your storage from client ( if you'd use S3 - that would be easy ) and then just tell your server to process it from there.

Comment: Hello @Martin, 
Thanks for your response and the change seems to be feasible to me. Next, I will give it a try.
Considering me a novice, I would further like to ask two more queries:
1. As you suggested,
>to create a background to process csv files and update DB. Because thsi could be long running task. So instead of processing the csv file directly during the POST request, you would schedule a task
Will you kindly elaborate a little, how can I do that.

2. Do you think if this approach of using a csv file to post bulk data is a good one or we should use a huge json instead ?

Comment: @farhat updated answer to answer your questions from the comment

Comment: Thanks for your support @Martin, it really helped me move forward with the issue.